# Overlap occurs when switching fragments with the Bottom Navigation Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a new project with the Bottom Navigation Activity. When I try to switch fragments through the buttons on the bottom navigation bar, the other fragment always overlaps the fragment started by default.
I set up four fragments to switch.

IndexActivity.java

```
public class IndexActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction transaction;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.message_id, R.id.friends_id, R.id.news_id,R.id.mine_id)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

    fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
    transaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new MessageFragment());
    transaction.commit();

    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener=new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.message_id:
                fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
                transaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new MessageFragment());
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.friends_id:
                fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
                transaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new FriendsFragment());
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.news_id:
                fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
                transaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new NewsFragment());
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.mine_id:
                fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
                transaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new MineFragment());
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

activity_index.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" >

</fragment>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S1eP.png)

I would really appreciate if someone could help me! Thank You!

Comment: You're using a `NavHostFragment`. That means you should not be doing **any** `FragmentTransaction` at all. Why are you doing that?

Comment: When I use auto create bottom navigation activity, it is generated automatically. Thank you for your advice anyway.